# Can not get the Flashlight to turn ON or OFF in my app - Swift

Tags: swift

I've added a UIButton to work as a toggle for the Flashlight in my camera view. I couldn't get the code that I added to work so I googled it and tried the code that another person was using and that doesn't work either.

This is the code:

```
import AVFoundation

@IBAction func toggleFlash(_ sender: UIButton) {

    func toggleFlash(on: Bool) {
        guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else { return }

        if device.hasTorch {
            do {
                try device.lockForConfiguration()

                if on == true {
                    device.torchMode = .on
                } else {
                    device.torchMode = .off
                }

                device.unlockForConfiguration()
            } catch {
                print("Torch could not be used")
            }
        } else {
            print("Torch is not available")
        }
    }

}
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with my code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you are just defining a function inside an @ibaction function but you never call it. What you can do is define your function outside of the @ibaction and call it when the button is pressed :

```
import AVFoundation

func toggleFlash(on: Bool) {
    guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else { return }

    if device.hasTorch {
        do {
            try device.lockForConfiguration()

            if on == true {
                device.torchMode = .on
            } else {
                device.torchMode = .off
            }

            device.unlockForConfiguration()
        } catch {
            print("Torch could not be used")
        }
    } else {
        print("Torch is not available")
    }
}

@IBAction func toggleFlash(_ sender: UIButton) {
    toggleFlash(on: true)
    //If you want to set it off just call toggleFlash(on : Falsse)
}
```